# table doesn't exist after login in fresh new session

Tags: mysql, corrupt

This is a weird one and definitely NOT one of the other cases I have seen when tables are corrupt...

I start off with a fresh clean session (clear browser history, sessions and cookies to initial in chrome, or any other browser) I can log in using the log-in-system of the website. When i'm logged in the website, every other page with MySQL queries will result in table does not exists error.

show table, create table, repair table select * from, drop table and any other manipulation to the tables results in the table does not exists error.

any possible scenario's on what could have happened?? Is it a known bug or anything? I did not move or change anything on the server that could cause this, nor did I try to drop a table.

The funny thing is that this is reproducible whenever I clear the browser history or sessions

some version information:

> innodb_version             1.1.8
> protocol_version   10
> slave_type_conversions    
> version                    5.5.15
> version_comment            MySQL Community Server (GPL)
> version_compile_machine    x86
> version_compile_os     Win64
>
> PHP Version              5.2.17

It always worked, until today

Comment: It's unlikely that this is a bug. You mentioned a login system, how is that related to the missing tables? Is it possible that you don't connect to the correct database?

Comment: Or misspelled the table name?

Comment: Have you checked your queries? I know from experience that mysql is capital sensitive, so if you wrote something with a capital in your query that isnt capitalized when it should be, it returns nothing. 

If that isnt the case, can you produce an error? So we might know what we are looking for. Did you echo out your query? And if so, did you check it with phpmyadmin or any other query checking program you use that is connected to your site?

Comment: I've seen that one..nothing stated that he logged in first (validate user name and password with the hash in the db) before the db got " corrupted " throw the session away and I can do it all over again!

@Dorvalla nope, tried that one...@Erik, nope, copied right from the list with tables I got ;) besides, every query fails, EVEN the ones that worked before...

Comment: @Dorvalla, the queries are correct, they did work yesterday and now they don't without changing them

Answer (score 0):

We've got the solution, we use multiple databases for several purposes. a colleague of mine changed the file with the connection with the main database on top and a second database connect statement after that one. since the database names where the same we did not notice this.